# How to search for words separated by arbitrary whitespace?

Tags: latex, search, whitespace

The question is general, but here's a specific case:

In LaTeX source files, it doesn't matter if two words are separated by one space character, multiple space characters, or even a linebreak - in the compiled document, the two words are just separated by one space. Many people will insert linebreaks to do manual line wrapping when writing LaTeX.

If I want to search a phrase containing multiple words inside the LaTeX source file, is Emacs able to disregard the white space ambiguities described above when searching?

Comment: Does [`(info "(emacs) Lax Search")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lax-Search.html) answer your question?

Comment: @Basi Thanks for the link, I just need `(setq search-whitespace-regexp "[[:space:]\n]+")`

Comment: Please either add that as an answer or delete the question. Comments can be deleted at any time. Q&A need to stand on their own (only they are searchable). Also: it's possible that this question is a duplicate - please search for that, and if so, delete it. Thx.

Comment: @phils thanks for the language advice, please feel free to suggest alternative wording. (Unfortunately I don't think I can edit the question anymore.)

Answer (score 2):

Following the link of @Basil, here's the needed ELisp code.

```
(setq search-whitespace-regexp "[[:space:]\n]+"))
```

To enable this whenever I edit LaTeX documents, I added the following code to my init file.

```
(defun my-latex-search-setting ()
  (setq search-whitespace-regexp "[[:space:]\n]+"))
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook #'my-latex-search-setting)
```

Now if I press Ctrl-s to search for `hello world`, Emacs will match e.g.

```
hello    world
```

as well as

```
hello
world
```

Comment: `search-whitespace-regexp` is a global setting, so it doesn't make sense to set it in a mode hook. You should either set it globally or make it buffer local (`(make-local-variable 'search-whitespace-regexp)` in the mode hook before the assignment).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thanks, I've changed it to
`(defun my-latex-search-setting () (make-local-variable 'search-whitespace-regexp) (setq search-whitespace-regexp "[[:space:]\n]+"))`